# Why is this MySQL query slow?

Tags: mysql

I have the following query, all relevant columns are indexed correctly. MySQL version 5.0.8.  The query takes forever:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `members` `t` WHERE t.member_type NOT IN (1,2)
AND ( SELECT end_date FROM subscriptions s
WHERE s.sub_auth_id = t.member_auth_id AND s.sub_status = 'Completed'
AND s.sub_pkg_id > 0 ORDER BY s.id DESC LIMIT 1 ) < curdate( )
```

`EXPLAIN` output:

```
----+--------------------+-------+-------+-----------------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------
id  | select_type        | table | type  | possible_keys         | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra
----+--------------------+-------+-------+-----------------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------
1   | PRIMARY            | t     | ALL   | membership_type       | NULL    | NULL    | NULL | 9610 | Using where
----+--------------------+-------+-------+-----------------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------
2   | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | s     | index | subscription_auth_id, | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL |    1 | Using where
    |                    |       |       | subscription_pkg_id,  |         |         |      |      |            
    |                    |       |       | subscription_status   |         |         |      |      |            
----+--------------------+-------+-------+-----------------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------
```

Why?

Comment: Post the results of `EXPLAIN` on that query so we can understand what the query engine thinks of it compared to your database.

Comment: Members table has 9610 rows, the subscriptions table has 14,518

Comment: id  select_type     table  type  possible_keys         key     key_len  ref  rows  Extra
1  PRIMARY          t       ALL  membership_type     NULL     NULL NULL 9610  Using where
2  DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  s      index  subscription_auth_id, PRIMARY   4      NULL 1      Using where
                                        subscription_pkg_id,
          subscription_status

Comment: 1. Put `EXPLAIN` 2. Put `create table` 3. What did you tried except indexing? 4. Did you tried to rewrite query?

Comment: Rewrite the subquery as a join.

Comment: Why are you asking these questions ravnur?  Rewrite the query how? It must return a single row for each member meeting the conditions of the sub select. To me it looks simple enough, however for some reason MySQL clearly does not like it.

Comment: DCoder - rewrite the sub query as a join how? The subscriptions table can have multiple rows for the same member, we must get the last record.

Answer (score 2):

Your query is slow because as written you are considering 9,610 rows and therefore performing 9,610 SELECT subqueries in your WHERE clause. You really should rewrite your query to JOIN the `members` and `subscriptions` tables first, to which your WHERE conditions could still apply.

**EDIT:** Try this.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM `members` `t`
JOIN subscriptions s ON (s.sub_auth_id = t.member_auth_id)
WHERE t.member_type NOT IN (1,2)
AND s.sub_status = 'Completed'
AND s.sub_pkg_id > 0
AND end_date < curdate()
ORDER BY s.id DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Your subselect refers to values in the parent query. This is known as a [correlated (dependent) subquery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery), and such a query has to be executed once for every row in the parent query, which often leads to poor performance. It is often faster to rewrite the query as a JOIN, for example like this

(**Note:** without a sample schema to test with, it is impossible to say in advance if this will be faster and still correct, you might need to adjust it a little):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM members t 
LEFT JOIN (
 SELECT sub_auth_id as member_id, max(id) as sid FROM subscriptions
 WHERE sub_status = 'Completed'
 AND sub_pkg_id > 0
 GROUP BY sub_auth_id
 LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT id AS subid, end_date FROM subscriptions
  WHERE sub_status = 'Completed'
  AND sub_pkg_id > 0
 ) sdate ON sid = subid
) sub ON sub.member_id = t.member_auth_id
WHERE t.member_type NOT IN (1,2)
AND sub.end_date < curdate( )
```

The logic here is:

1. For each member, find his latest subscription.
2. For each latest subscription, find its end date.
3. Join these member-latest_sub_date pair to the members list.
4. Filter the list.

Answer (score 0):

Caveat: I'm not a MySQL expert, but pretty good in a different SQL flavour (VFP), but I believe you will save some time if:

1. You count just one field, let's say memberid, instead of *.
2. Your comparison `NOT IN (1,2)` is replaced with `> 2` (provided that is valid).
3. The `ORDER BY` in your subselect is unnecessary, I think. You're trying to get the last  completed subscription?
4. The `< curdate()` should be inside your subselect's `WHERE`.

   ```
   (SELECT end_date FROM subscriptions s
   WHERE s.end_date < curdate() and s.sub_auth_id = t.member_auth_id AND 
   s.sub_status =  'Completed' AND s.sub_pkg_id > 0 ORDER BY s.id DESC LIMIT 1 )
   ```
5. Tune your subselect so as to trim down the set as quickly as possible. The first conditional should be the one least likely to occur.

Comment: `COUNT(*)` is not necessarily slower than `COUNT(ID)`. See http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/04/10/count-vs-countcol/

Comment: Yes, the comparison can be replaced, although that is not what slows the query.  Yes, trying to get the last completed subscription.  Essentially, if end_date < curdate().  This is to show members with expired subscriptions.  I can't see how your example for the sub select can be a condition of the main select.

Comment: count(*) is definitely not the problem.

Comment: Order of [`selections`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_Algebra#Selection_.28.CF.83.29) made in where clause does not matter at all.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing it like this:

```
select count(*) from members t 
JOIN subscriptions s ON s.sub_auth_id = t.member_auth_id
WHERE t.membership_type > 2 AND s.sub_status = 'Completed' AND s.sub_pkg_id > 0 
AND  s.sub_end_date < curdate( ) 
AND s.id = (SELECT MAX(ss.id) FROM subscriptions ss WHERE ss.sub_auth_id =   t.member_auth_id)
```

I believe that the problem is due to a bug that won't be fixed until MySQL 6.